# facebook graph api photo sharedposts summary

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can i get the share count on a page photo from facebook graph API ? I know i can get the first shared posts using 'sharedposts' field, but i'm looking only for the total share count, just like you can get the total like count using this:

```
&fields=likes.summary(1).limit(0)
```

but if i try something like that for the 'sharedposts' field, it doesn't work (with or without a limit) :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/xxxxxxxx/photos/sharedposts?access_token=xxxxxxxxxx&debug=all&fields=sharedposts.summary(1).limit(9999),created_time,images,name,likes.summary(1).limit(0),caption&format=json&method=get&pretty=1&suppress_http_code=1&limit=999999
```

since i'm already doing a very long query to get all the photos from a page (10000+), i really would like to avoid to double the amount of queries to 20k using this way : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo/sharedposts/

Comment: sharedposts does not have a summary, so there is no other way. And be aware that going through all shared posts to count them will of course not give you an accurate number either - because your app will only get to “see” shares it has access to; so that means for shares by users, your app would need user_posts permission from that user first.